# JS function does not update HTML string

Tags: javascript, html

Im pretty new to JS and HTML (started ~20 hours ago) and already have a problem: below you can see my code. As one tutorial said, clicking on button will change the statusLine text. But something went wrong and i cant figure it out.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Некое подземелье</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="statusLine">Вы попали в подземелье.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="goDeeper()">Идти глубже в подземелье</button>

<script>
    function goDeeper()
     {
       var nextEvent=(Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1));
       switch(nextEvent){
        case'1':
            document.getElementById("statusLine").innerHTML="Вам на пути попался гоблин!";
            break;
                }
     }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, something is wrong. What should i do in order to fix this?

Comment: What does the javascript console say? And what should happen if `nextEvent` is not `'1'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the case statement match the number `1` rather than the string `'1'`:

```
function goDeeper()
{
    var nextEvent = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
    switch(nextEvent) {
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("statusLine").innerHTML="Вам на пути попался гоблин!";
            break;
    }
}
```

Or for that matter, if there is only one condition you need to match, just get rid of the `switch` and use a simple `if` block:

```
function goDeeper()
{
    var nextEvent = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
    if (nextEvent == 1) {
        document.getElementById("statusLine").innerHTML="Вам на пути попался гоблин!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
What I understand you want to change the text on click button so Try this 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello World";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>`enter code here`

</body>
</html>

Refrence Link : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick
```